# NamedStoredProcedureQuery Output Map<key, entity>

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring Data JPA NamedStoredProcedureQuery to Out Multiple Parameters from Procedure Oracle DB

> In entity class:

```
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "Ent.getCust", resultClasses = CustomerEntity.class, 
            procedureName = "pkg.p_get_cust", parameters = {
            @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "p_username", type = String.class),
            @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.OUT, name = "o_local_code", type = String.class),
            @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR, name = "o_result", type = Void.class) }) })
```

> in Repository interface

```
@Repository
public interface CustomerRepositoryExt extends JpaRepository<CustomerEntity, Long> {

   @Procedure(name = "Ent.getCust")
   Map<String, CustomerEntity> getCust(@Param("p_username") String username);
}
```

Currently this code return error:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Direct self-reference leading to cycle (through reference chain: java.util.HashMap["o_result"]->oracle.jdbc.driver.ForwardOnlyResultSet["statement"]->oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement["connection"]->oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection["wrapper"])
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:460)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:290)
```

I don't know, can Spring Data JPA support return this result?

Answer (score 0):

I don't guess oracle output types are directly supported in java object types (have tried myself a lot but in vain).
You are possibly trying to map o_result refcursor to CustomerEntity directly which is a not so a good idea tbh.
I would rather recommend go old school on this and use `entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery` to make the oracle procedure calls.

It would looks something like this:
define the StoredProcedureQuery with your proc name and register the output refcursor and string parameter o_local_code as ResultSet objects.

```
storedProcedureQuery.registerStoredProcedureParameter("o_result", void.class, ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR);
storedProcedureQuery.registerStoredProcedureParameter("o_local_code", String.class, ParameterMode.OUT); 
ResultSet rs = (ResultSet)storedProcedureQuery.getOutputParameterValue("o_result");
```

Loop through the resultset and build your CustomerEntity.
A good reason to do this would be to be able to build a `List<CustomerEntity>` from the mutlirow refcursor (if it does return multiple rows).